# Access a 2nd project in the same solution with MSBuild

Tags: msbuild

I'm new to MSBuild, and am learning as I need to know how to do things. Currently, I am working form the MSBuild file that is generated from the Web Deployment Project extension for Visual Studio. I have been ab;e to access and manipulate files which are directly in my Web project by creating properties form this block of XML:

```
  <PropertyGroup>
    <Configuration Condition=" '$(Configuration)' == '' ">Debug</Configuration>
    <Platform Condition=" '$(Platform)' == '' ">AnyCPU</Platform>
    <ProductVersion>9.0.21022</ProductVersion>
    <SchemaVersion>2.0</SchemaVersion>
    <ProjectGuid>{0B9F9B60-7AD7-49F0-A168-9D4D29FB1A21}</ProjectGuid>
    <SourceWebPhysicalPath>..\ARP_FORMS</SourceWebPhysicalPath>
    <SourceWebProject>{7FCA4A38-0FEE-4D46-82EF-AD0089F9CAA2}|ARP_FORMS\ARP_FORMS.csproj</SourceWebProject>
    <SourceWebVirtualPath>/ARP_FORMS.csproj</SourceWebVirtualPath>
    <TargetFrameworkVersion>v3.5</TargetFrameworkVersion>
  </PropertyGroup>
```

I need to create properties do the same thing to manipulate other files from additional projects in my solution. Can anyone point me to the proper syntax for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sayed Ibrahim Hashimi [answers this question](http://www.sedodream.com/PermaLink,guid,ed3a0c98-fdac-4467-9116-5b3bf6755abc.aspx) very well, and he includes sample source code. Basically, you create an MSBuild project that executes other MSBuild projects.